# Mirroring of database on same server for tersting

Tags: database, mirroring, database-mirroring

Is possible to mirror to database of same sql server . My server instance is SQLSERVER having 2 database with same structure but with differ name . i want db1 to sync with db2, so if i want user to test application i can do it.

Comment: Hi there is an SO site for questions about database admin http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even though I would not recommend having them on the same sql server (performance/security wise), just have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207006.aspx

(since you said SQLSERVER, I guess you meant mssql)